# Include external ES modules in the bundle

Tags: typescript, kotlin, esbuild, kotlin-js, esmodules

I'm  getting an error when running esbuild complaining:

```
You can mark the path "hiom" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.
```

This is my `esbuild.config.build.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const {files} = require("./esbuild.config.entry");
require("esbuild").build({
    entryPoints: [...files],
    bundle: true,
    minify: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    target: ["chrome100", "firefox100", "safari16.6.1", "edge100"],
    outdir: "./dist/static",
    logLevel: "info",
    loader: {
        ".woff": "file",
        ".woff2": "file",
        ".ttf": "file",
        ".svg": "file",
        ".png": "file",
        ".eot": "file"
    },
}).catch(() => process.exit(1))
```

and my `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "my project",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "./node_modules/.bin/concurrently --kill-others --names tsc,esbuild.config.start.js \\\"./esbuild.config.start.js\\\"",
        "build": "./node_modules/.bin/rimraf dist && ./esbuild.config.build.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "hiom": "../../build/js/packages/hiom",
        "tslib": "2.6.2",
        "uhtml": "3.2.2"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^8.2.1",
        "esbuild": "^0.19.4",
        "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2"
    }
}
```

and I've tried with the other path as well:

```
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "hiom": "../hi-server/build/dist/js/productionLibrary",
        "tslib": "2.6.2",
        "uhtml": "3.2.2"
    },
    ...
```

The error message says I need to mark `hiom` as external

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const {files} = require("./esbuild.config.entry");
require("esbuild").build({
    external: ["hiom"],   <<<
    ...
```

Doing this makes the error go away, but now `npm run build` doesn't bundle the `hiom` package which now causes `index.html` to throw an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Dynamic require of "hiom/kotlin/my-project-applications-my-server" is not supported
```

The `hiom` library I'm trying to include is generated by KotlinJS, it's generating ES modules:

[image]

[image]

Snippet from `build.gradle.kts`:

```
    js(IR) {
        useEsModules()
        binaries.library()
        moduleName = "hiom"
        browser {
            testTask {
                enabled = false
            }
        }
        generateTypeScriptDefinitions()
    }
```

If I don't use the `useEsModules`, option and it generates normal CommonJS .js files, then ESBuild has no problem bundling the generated JS. But when it's ES modules, it complains that I need to mark it as external, which then causes it to be excluded.

What are my options to include these generated ES modules in my ES Build and eventually have it in my `index.html`?

EDIT:

I don't know if my tsconfig would be of any help:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ES2020",
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I've also tried switching the whole project to use esmodules. Not sure if I'm doing it correctly or not.

Udating package.json and setting:

```
"type": "module",
```

and changing esbuild.config.build.js

```
import {files} from "./esbuild.config.entry.js"

console.log("----------------------------------------")
console.log(files)
console.log("----------------------------------------")

import {build} from "esbuild"

build({
    format: "esm",
    entryPoints: [...files],
    bundle: true,
    minify: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    target: ["chrome100", "firefox100", "safari16.6.1", "edge100"],
    outdir: "./dist/static",
    logLevel: "info",
    loader: {
        ".woff": "file",
        ".woff2": "file",
        ".ttf": "file",
        ".svg": "file",
        ".png": "file",
        ".eot": "file"
    },
}).catch(() => process.exit(1))
```

The error still remains

Comment: _"which will remove this error"_ - ...what error? If you want it in the bundle then making it external is exactly wrong.

Comment: sure, but if I don't mark it external, then it doesn't build. So how do I get it into the bundle or if that is not supported, how do I get the JS to load correctly on index.html?.